Why is “dd” slower than balenaEtcher in my usage case?
I regularly have to flash an SD card with a .wic image. I have tried two tools, linux's dd and balenaEtcher.
balenaEtcher finishes the job in about 2 minutes while my dd command takes 5.
Here is the dd command that works properly but takes too much time:
dd if=sdimage.wic of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4M status=progress oflag=sync

Can anybody give me a hint as to how to get optimal speed with dd? I am guessing it has something to do with the block size (bs), but I am not sure how to choose that value.

"I am guessing it has something to do with the block size (bs)" - Yes, bigger (e.g. bs=4M) is not always better. There's no advantage to such a huge block size because a single I/O operation cannot transfer that amount of data. Someone once posted dd test results for various block-size values, and the transfer rate peaked IIRC somewhere at around 32K to 128K. oflag=sync will also increase program execution time.

You'd be better off sticking with Balena Etcher because it will perform a verify after write.

have you timed a simple cat? or pv if you want to see progress

@Bravo what do you mean by a simple cat? Can I flash my sd card using cat?

surprisingly, yes
